# Laravel Elasticquent getAggregations for average numbers in field

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm try to test function of elastic search on laravel 5.2 and elascticsearch 2.3 , i'm using packages :
https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent

I do index, mapping and addalltoindex for my table .

I'm able to use the search collection , but i'm stuck on how to use the getAggregations

My code as follows :

```
$gege = $receipts->getAggregations(array('aggs' => array('avg_amount' => array('avg' => array('field' => 'service_tax')))));
```

It returns :

[ ] only

If anyone would show me the exact way using these libraries to populate aggregations , i say thank you very much .

Comment: problem solves, should be using searchByQuery() , then getAggregations only render the result from searchByQuery()